# How to access angularJS model data from within an external jQuery piece of script?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have the following script included in a page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".fancy-class").chatter({
            hostname: 'http://www.domain.com',
            group: 'moustache',
            brand: '{{brand.name}}'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And I want brand to be set to a brand that I know is stored in my angular model.

How do I do this?

Comment: I think brand.name is wrong. just remove the quotes and try it

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS does not interpolate script like this. The recommended way to implement non-angular code that needs to interact with your angular application is write a custom directive.

I created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qeG7MBWWkd1l04ExHqrO?p=preview) that illustrates how you might handle your example via a directive.

Highlight (JS):

```
  angular.module("demo", [])
    // omitted for brevity
    .directive('fancyClass', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'C', // directive is triggered via a class name called fancy-class
        scope: {
          'brand': '&' // lets us use an attribute named brand to declare the scope value containing the value we want
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          // initializes the jQuery plugin, using the scope value for brand
          element.chatter({
            hostname: 'http://www.domain.com',
            group: 'moustache',
            brand: scope.brand()
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

Using it on a tag in your view:

```
<span class="fancy-class" brand="fancyValue">Fancy 1</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own global comunicator so that both angular and jquery access to it.